# keras' ModelCheckpoint not working

Tags: keras, convolutional-neural-network

I'm trying to train a model in keras and I'm using [ModelCheckpoint](https://keras.io/callbacks/#modelcheckpoint) to save the best model according to a monitored validation metric (in my case the [Jaccard index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index)).

While I can see the model improving in tensorboard, when I try to load the weights and evaluate the model it isn't working at all. Furthermore, by the timestamp on the file where the weights are supposed to be stored, I can tell that they are not being saved at all. The timestamp corresponds roughly to the time I started training.

Has anyone encountered such a problem before?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you run `ModelCheckpoint` on its default parameters (besides `monitor`)?

`ModelCheckpoint` has a parameter called `mode` which specifies the **type** of metric to be used. `mode` can take 3 values `'min'` `'max'` and `'auto'` (which is the default):

- `min`: means that you want to *minimize* the metric (e.g. the loss function).
- `max`: means you want to *maximize* the metric (e.g. accuracy).
- `auto`: attempts to figure what to do on its own. If you look at the [code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/callbacks.py#L417), it checks if the metric's name contains `'acc'` or if it starts with `'fmeasure'`. If yes it sets the mode to `max`, if not it sets it to `min`.

In your case, you monitor the jaccard index, which is a metric you want maximized, so you want the mode set to `max`. Normally because "jaccard" contains the string "acc", even if the mode is set to `auto` it should work fine.

If however you named your metric something arbitrary (e.g. `my_metric`), the default mode will be set to `min`, which means that it will store the weights that achieve the **least** performance on your metric, which should be the weights of the first epoch.

**Suggestion**: next time try with `mode='max'` to be sure.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I had named my metric `intersection_over_union` and it was probably storing weights that had the lowest score, which were the ones from the first epoch. That makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help!